# Beginner python pig latin converter

Tags: python

I just started python lessons and tried to code my version of the pig latin transformation then I ran into a problem I can't seem to figure out.

See the code below.

```
def pig_latin(text):
  say = []
  # Separate the text into words
  words = text.split()
  for word, wor_te in enumerate(words):
    # Create the pig latin word and add it to the list
     old_w=""
     new_w = "{}".format(wor_te).replace(str(wor_te[0]),old_w).join(("",wor_te[0]+"ay"))
     say.append(new_w)
    # Turn the list back into a phrase
  say= " ".join(say)
  say ='{}'.format(say)
  return say

print(pig_latin("hello how are you")) # Should be "ellohay owhay reaay ouyay"
print(pig_latin("programming in python is fun")) # Should be "rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay"
print(pig_latin("writing interesting functions")) # Should be "ritingway nterestingiay unctionsfay"
```

from the script above, this line below is the input that highlights the issue

```
print(pig_latin("writing interesting functions"))
```

See the output of the code below:

```
ellohay owhay reaay ouyay
rogrammingpay niay ythonpay siay unfay
ritingway nterestngiay unctionsfay
```

the last sentence is missing a letter in the second word highlighted.

```
ritingway **nterestngiay** unctionsfay
```

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()`? You never use the `word` variable for anything.

Comment: You don't want to use replace.  That causes you to remove the first letter wherever it occurs in the word.  You just want to remove the first letter.  `word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay'`

Comment: @Barmar I was making this script to get familiar with methods and functions in python but in doing that I see now I made it too complicated. This is my 4 official day learning python btw so a lot of the concepts are not clear to me. your suggestion helped to fix the issue though, thanks a lot.

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah I used that and it worked, lol I spent all that time to think about that line when the solution was an even smaller line. the wonders of python, haha.

Comment: @fort3 For an absolute beginner, this is not too bad and the mistake is very understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace()` replaces all occurrences of a substring. So if the first letter of the word is repeated, `replace(str(wor_te[0]),old_w)` will remove all of them. So this turns `interesting` into `nterestng` because it removes both `i` characters.

If you want to remove the first letter of a word, use a slice: `wor_te[1:]`.

Your use of `format()` and `join()` is also overly complicated. Just use `+` to concatenate strings.

```
    new_w = wor_te[1:] + wor_te[0] + "ay"
```

Answer (score 0):

`interesting` begins with the letter i, and it also contains another i near the end.

When you call `replace(str(wor_te[0]),old_w)`, that removes *all* the i's.

Comment: yeah I didn't understand why it behave that way, its my 4th day of learning python so I guess such concepts might be hard to understand for beginners in python.

Comment: I still wonder why it skipped the word before it though cos that also contained more than one i